# Javascript Charting Library: Funnel Chart with specific funcitons

Tags: javascript, charts, onclick, datapoint

So i have to create a **Funnelchart** with specific datapoints on it, so the funnel features different **sections**, and those sections have **Points** with Metadata in it. 
I need a javascript library to accomplish this.

The datapoints need to do the following:

- they must be **styled independantly**, so for example one can be red and the other one blue and a circle around it
- they need an **onclickevent** (or similar) so if clicked the script can change data and styling of the datapoint
- they need to be placed dependent on the width and height of each funnel section. so i need to get the **boundaries**, for example: 
  funnel has sections [A,B,C], i need to get something like minimum and maximum of X and Y for each funnelsection. so i know where to place the datapoints.

Unfortunately, most charting libraries only seem to support predefined charts with little datapoint customisation options.
Does anyone know a charting library where this task is somewhat intuitive and easy to do?

Comment: Have you looked at D3? There is a library called D3Funnel you might be interested in [Git Hub here](http://jakezatecky.github.io/d3-funnel/) || [Examples here](http://jakezatecky.github.io/d3-funnel/)

Comment: [Another example](https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel/blob/master/examples/examples.js)

Comment: Thank you for your response, J Newton. Unfortunately, d3funnel.js wont allow to place datapoints on the sections, at least without doing it from scratch.